# Get empty response data when variable not defined

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I try to use following code to check response of a `HTTP Request`, which is called from another `Thread Group` by a `Module Controller`.

```
File myfile = new File(FileServer.resolveBaseRelativeName("results/" + filen + "-report.xml"));

if(${__isVarDefined(vars.get("myvar"))} == true){
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(myfile,bytes);
} else {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myfile, prev.getResponseDataAsString(), "UTF-8");
}
```

Empty `xml` is created when `myvar` variable is empty, it doesn't contains response data of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write byte[] in both cases using [getResponseData()](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseData--) (and removed function call)

```
if(vars.get("myvar") ! null){
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(myfile, bytes);
} else {
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(myfile, prev.getResponseData());
}
```

Comment: `prev.getResponseData()` seems null, but HTTP Request got response.

Comment: @plaidshirt do you have other post processor that manipulate result?

Comment: I use multiple JSON Path Extractors to get values.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use `vars` shorthand to retrieve values from the different Thread Group as JMeter Variables are local to the Thread hence they cannot be accessed from another Thread Group. You need to use `props` instead. See the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   > Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.
2. [Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables in Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), if you need to check whether variable is defined or not - attempt to get it and see if it is `null`:

   ```
   if (vars.get('myvar') != null) {
       //the code will be executed if the var is defined
   }
   ```

Check out `Transferring Data and Objects (like List, Maps, Array etc.) Between Samplers and Threads` chapter of [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter for more details](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter).

---

In the absolute majority of cases it's easier to use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

Comment: Variable myvar is present in actual thread group, prev.getResponseDataAsString() should come from the other one.

Comment: You need to do something like `props.put('response', prev.getResponseDataAsString())` in 1st Thread Group and `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myfile, props.get('response'), 'UTF-8')` in 2nd Thread Group

Comment: I see, but in this case I save response in each cases to property value, but I don't use it in most cases.